# Get email after clicking button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to capture the email after the customer clicks on the button next to the email, I tried some options but I lose the email information when I click.

To simulate, access the website

```
https://opill.com/
```

go to the end where the email field is, click on the checkbox and then on the arrow inside the email form.

```
document.querySelectorAll("#email_74140190")
```

Get the email in an attribute after click

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question itself

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You're using a NodeList to capture a single element. Have you logged what `document.querySelectorAll("#email_74140190")` actually returns? I wouldn't suggest using `querySelectorAll()` with an id selector, since ids should be unique; I would use `document.querySelector("#email_74140190")` (without the "All") instead.